# Which iOS frameworks most useful to learn and in what order?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, ios

I've just started learning Obj-C and the Cocoa-Touch framework for developing iPhone and iPad applications. When you add a framework to an XCode project I can't help notice there are an enormous number to get familiar e.g. AddressBook, CoreData, Foundation, Security etc.

- Which frameworks are common to most
  projects and the most important to
  master i.e. UIKit?
- Which frameworks
  will require a prerequisite
  level of understanding of another?
- Which frameworks are application specific
  and can be left until needed i.e.
  Accelerate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really just learn them as you run into a need for them.

UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation are a good subset that will let you do most applications though.

Comment: Yeah, I second this answer. Don't concern yourself with specific frameworks. Once you know what you want to do with your app you'll need to acquaint yourself with various frameworks, but not really until then. It's easy to figure out which frameworks are needed for certain features, but the ones listed above are a good starting point.